# How to autofill Git commit messages?

Tags: git

Often during work I'm dogmatically doing:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'wip'
```

Often this is less than useful when I'm viewing history.

Is there a way to automatically have Git fill in the commit message with files that changed?

```
git commit --autofill
```

```
src/dir/file ++2, 712
src/dir/file2 --2, 123
```

Comment: But… that information is already part of the commit. Why duplicate it in the message?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `commit-msg` hook.

```
#!/bin/sh

readonly MSG="$1"
sed -n -e '1p' $MSG \
    | if grep -qE '^wip';then
          git diff --cached --stat | sed -e '$d' > $MSG
      fi
```

`git commit -m 'wip'` would replace the commit message with cache diff statics:

```
 foo/1.txt        | 6 +++---
 bar/2.txt        | 1 +
```

If the message does not start with `wip`, it would be as is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git commit --fixup/squash` in addition with `git rebase -i --autosquash target_branch`.

The first command will create  a commit with staged change that will take the comment from previous commit and add `fixup!` or `squash!` in front of him.

It shoud look like

```
aaa1111 fixup! Commit message
aaa2222 Commit message
```

Secondly with the `--autosquash` option `git rebase` will automatically mark those commit as to fixed up or to squash.